# what order is Process.GetProcesses() getting the processes?

Tags: c#, windows

in what order is Process.GetProcesses() getting the processes?

not finding anything relevant in the official documentation 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Isn't it easier and faster to try it and see the result yourself?

Comment: Already tried but no luck, I'm not finding what is the criteria

Comment: IIRC, the kernel keeps a linked list of all processes, so it probably returns them in the order they are in the list, i.e., there is no predictable criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying Win32 APIs that are used are [`Process32First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`Process32Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684836(v=vs.85).aspx). Neither of these APIs document that they will be returned in order, thus you cannot depend on them being given to you in a particular order every time. If you need them sorted, then sort them using LINQ or any other means.

Comment: An idea of how to print all processes, ordered by name: `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().OrderBy(x => x.ProcessName).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ProcessName));` It is also worth mentioning that using CMD's `tasklist` gives another random order.